# Create large amount of nodes in a neo4j database from List in Java

Tags: java, csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of 10.000 names in a Java program. I would like to create/merge a node for each of them in a Neo4j 3.3.0 database.

I know that I can contact the database through

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and send Cypher queries. I would like to avoid sending thousands of individual queries to the database. I read about the possibility of reading CSV files, but it seems strange to first write CSV file from Java, make it available through http to give it to the database.

Comment: The list of names in Java contains duplicates?

Comment: @BrunoPeres No. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FOREACH` function to process all the names passed in via a single list parameter. This is very similar to @BrunoPeres' answer, but perhaps a bit more readable.

```
try ( Session session = driver.session() )
{
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("Jon");
    list.add("Doe");
    list.add("Bruno");

    session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public String execute( Transaction tx )
        {
            StatementResult result = tx.run(
                    "FOREACH(name IN $names | CREATE (p:Person) SET p.name = name)",
                    parameters( "names", list ) );
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: The `FOREACH` function can only accept (after the `|`) Cypher clauses that write to the DB (like `CREATE` and `SET`).

Answer (score 2):

Try passing your list as parameter, then `UNWIND` the list and `CREATE` the nodes.

```
try ( Session session = driver.session() )
{
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add("Jon");
    list.add("Doe");
    list.add("Bruno");

    session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public String execute( Transaction tx )
        {
            StatementResult result = tx.run( "UNWIND $names as name" +
                                             "CREATE (p:Person) SET p.name = name",
                    parameters( "names", list ) );
        }
    });
}
```